# This javascript form validation won't go through even when the fields have been filled in. Any advice?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkforinput() {

    if (document.getElementById('fname').value == "") {
        document.getElementById('fname').style.borderColor = "red";
        document.getElementById('errMsg').innerHTML = "*Please enter First and Last Name";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('fname').style.borderColor = "#c5c5c5";
        document.getElementById('errMsg').innerHTML = "";
    }

    if (document.getElementById('lname').value == "") {
        document.getElementById('lname').style.borderColor = "red";
        document.getElementById('errMsg2').innerHTML = "*Please enter First and Last Name";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('lname').style.borderColor = "#c5c5c5";
        document.getElementById('errMsg2').innerHTML = "";
    }

    if (document.getElementById('email').value == "") {
        document.getElementById('email').style.borderColor = "red";
        document.getElementById('errMsg3').innerHTML = "*Please enter a valid email";
    } else {
        document.getElementById('email').style.borderColor = "#c5c5c5";
        document.getElementById('errMsg3').innerHTML = "";
    }

    return false;
}
</script>
```

Hey guys. So my question is regarding this chunk of Javascript code. So these inputs (fname, lname, and email) have a span right next to them with the id errMsg that will display whatever the value of .innerHTML is. The validation works. Except whenever I fill in all the fields completely, my submit button won't process the form action i have in place. Nothing happens. Any ideas as to why this is happening. I feel it has to do something with the ELSE in the conditional statement but i don't know what it is exactly. The reason I use ELSE here, is because it turns the field back to how it looked like before. But maybe its actually screwing me over here. I need help guys. Any advice is appreciated.
This is my HTML code:

```
<form name="postform" action="postingprocessed.php" method="post" onsubmit="return checkforinput()">
    <div class="fullName">
        <input id="fname" type="text" maxlength="100" placeholder="First Name" name="first_name" /><span id="errMsg"></span>
        <input id="lname" type="text" maxlength="100" placeholder="Last Name" name="last_name" /><span id="errMsg2"></span> 
    </div>
    <input id="email" class="text" type="email" maxlength="100" placeholder="Email" name="email" /><span id="errMsg3"></span>
    <br>
    <input id="submitBtn" class="submitBtn" type="submit" value="Post This!" name="SubmitBtn" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my submit button won't process the form action i have in place. Nothing happens.

Because you always return `false`, which tells browser not to process form. Return false only if some field is invalid and `true` otherwise:

```
var valid = true;

if (document.getElementById('fname').value == "") {
    document.getElementById('fname').style.borderColor = "red";
    document.getElementById('errMsg').innerHTML = "*Please enter First and Last Name";
    valid = false;
} else {
    document.getElementById('fname').style.borderColor = "#c5c5c5";
    document.getElementById('errMsg').innerHTML = "";
}

// ...

return valid;
```

Another recommendation. Don't use styles like your are now, this makes your code pretty obtrussive, verbose and hard to maintain (imagine, you want to change error border color - you need to change it on every field). Use CSS classes instead.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this please? Sorry, ive only been programming for about a month. A lot of this stuff is still pretty new to me. Do I just put return valid at the end of the script?

Answer (score 0):

This will only submit the form if all the input is valid :) What we're doing is set flag=1 if any input is empty/invalid and in the end if flag is 1, form won't be submitted otherwise it will be submitted.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkforinput() {
var flag=0;
if (document.getElementById('fname').value == ""){
document.getElementById('fname').style.borderColor = "red";
document.getElementById('errMsg').innerHTML = "*Please enter First and Last Name";
flag=1;
}    
else {
document.getElementById('fname').style.borderColor = "#c5c5c5";
document.getElementById('errMsg').innerHTML = "";
}

if (document.getElementById('lname').value == ""){
document.getElementById('lname').style.borderColor = "red";
document.getElementById('errMsg2').innerHTML = "*Please enter First and Last Name";
flag=1;
}
else {
document.getElementById('lname').style.borderColor = "#c5c5c5";
document.getElementById('errMsg2').innerHTML = "";
}

if (document.getElementById('email').value == ""){
document.getElementById('email').style.borderColor = "red";
document.getElementById('errMsg3').innerHTML = "*Please enter a valid email";
flag=1;
}
else {
document.getElementById('email').style.borderColor = "#c5c5c5";
document.getElementById('errMsg3').innerHTML = "";
}
if(flag)
   return false;
else
   return true;
}
</script>
```